# INNER Join ORACLE

Tags: oracle, inner-join

I am having a issue with my INNER join for Oracle. I was hoping you guys could review. Basically the Address table houses addresses of incident and person. I basically need to do a SELECT statement for the incident address then an INNER join to get the persons address as well, for some reason it is not working.

```
 select DISTINCT  INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INC_REPORT_NUMBER,trunc((to_number(to_char            (offense_status_date,'yyyymmdd'))-to_number(to_char(DOB,'yyyymmdd')))/10000)  as AGE,
 INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID,
 OFFENSES.OFFENSE_STATUS_DATE,
 INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.AGNCY_CD_AGENCY_CODE,
 INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.STATUS,
 INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.SEX_SEX_CODE,
  INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.RACE_RACE_CODE,
 INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.LNAME,
 INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.FNAME,
   INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.DOB,
 OFFENSES.REMARKS,
 OFFENSE_CODES.OFFENSE_DESC,
 P.LONGITUDE,P.LATITUDE,
 suspicion_Codes.DESCRIPTION,
 P.STREET_NUMBER, P.STREET_NAME,P.STREET_CD_STREET_TYPE_CODE,P.CITY,P.STATE_CD_STATE_CODE,P.ZIP5,
 AH.STREET_NUMBER,    AH.STREET_NAME,AH.STREET_CD_STREET_TYPE_CODE,AH.CITY,AH.STATE_CD_STATE_CODE,AH.ZIP5
 from
 INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW,
 OFFICER_INCIDENTS,OFFENSES,OFFENSE_CODES, OFFICERS,
 ADDRESSES P, INCIDENT_ADDRESSES,offender_suspicions,suspicion_Codes,person_addresses D
 INNER JOIN ADDRESSES ah
 ON D.address_id= ah.address_ID
 where OFFICER_INCIDENTS.INC_INCIDENT_ID=INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
 AND INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID=INCIDENT_ADDRESSES.INCIDENT_ID
 AND INCIDENT_ADDRESSES.ADDRESS_ID=P.ADDRESS_ID
 AND INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID = OFFENSES.INC_INCIDENT_ID
 AND INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID = OFFENDER_SUSPICIONS.OFFNSE_INC_INCIDENT_ID
 AND OFFENDER_SUSPICIONS.SUSPICN_CD_SUSPICION_CODE =SUSPICION_CODES.SUSPICION_CODE
 AND OFFENSES.OFFNS_CD_OFFENSE_CODE = OFFENSE_CODES.OFFENSE_CODE
 AND OFFICER_INCIDENTS.OFF1_OFFICER_ID = OFFICERS.OFFICER_ID
 and OFFICER_INCIDENTS.ORC_ROLE_CODE='R'
 and incident_people_vw.status='A'
 and INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.ROLE_ROLE_TYPE IN ('A','S')
 AND trunc((to_number(to_char(offense_status_date,'yyyymmdd'))-to_number(to_char    (DOB,'yyyymmdd')))/10000)  <= 17
```

Comment: please describe *how* it's not working. Oracle error (if so include the ORA number)? Missing results? Wrong address for the person?

Comment: The mixture of an inner join with joining the tables in the where clause makes the query more difficult to read. Much of your where clause can and should be expressed as inner joins.

Comment: The query works up until I add the "INNER JOIN ADDRESSES ah
 ON D.address_id= ah.address_ID"

Comment: Oracle error:ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.

Comment: `*Action: Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more files to the tablespace indicated` It's told you what you should do. So ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact reason for your query to fail is the one @Politank-Z wrote you ...

You are mixing ANSI syntax of joins with the "old" syntax with join predicates in the `WHERE` clause.

If you used the ANSI syntax consistently, you would easily spot the problem, being that your `person_addresses` table join lacks the actual join predicate and, as such, your DB server is doing a cartesian product instead, effectively devouring all of your temporary tablespace.

Here you are, a slight iterative revamp of your query ...

**Iteration 1** - introducing basic indentation and remaking all WHERE-clause join predicates to ANSI joins

```
select distinct
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INC_REPORT_NUMBER,
    trunc((to_number(to_char(offense_status_date,'yyyymmdd')) - to_number(to_char(DOB,'yyyymmdd')))/10000)  as AGE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID,
    OFFENSES.OFFENSE_STATUS_DATE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.AGNCY_CD_AGENCY_CODE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.STATUS,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.SEX_SEX_CODE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.RACE_RACE_CODE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.LNAME,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.FNAME,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.DOB,
    OFFENSES.REMARKS,
    OFFENSE_CODES.OFFENSE_DESC,
    P.LONGITUDE,P.LATITUDE,
    suspicion_Codes.DESCRIPTION,
    P.STREET_NUMBER, P.STREET_NAME,P.STREET_CD_STREET_TYPE_CODE,P.CITY,P.STATE_CD_STATE_CODE,P.ZIP5,
    AH.STREET_NUMBER, AH.STREET_NAME,AH.STREET_CD_STREET_TYPE_CODE,AH.CITY,AH.STATE_CD_STATE_CODE,AH.ZIP5
from
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW
    join OFFICER_INCIDENTS
        on OFFICER_INCIDENTS.INC_INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
    join OFFENSES
        on OFFENSES.INC_INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
    join OFFENSE_CODES
        on OFFENSE_CODES.OFFENSE_CODE = OFFENSES.OFFNS_CD_OFFENSE_CODE
    join OFFICERS
        on OFFICERS.OFFICER_ID = OFFICER_INCIDENTS.OFF1_OFFICER_ID
    join INCIDENT_ADDRESSES
        on INCIDENT_ADDRESSES.INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
    join ADDRESSES P
        on P.ADDRESS_ID = INCIDENT_ADDRESSES.ADDRESS_ID
    join offender_suspicions
        on OFFENDER_SUSPICIONS.OFFNSE_INC_INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
    join suspicion_Codes
        on SUSPICION_CODES.SUSPICION_CODE = OFFENDER_SUSPICIONS.SUSPICN_CD_SUSPICION_CODE
    person_addresses D,
    INNER JOIN ADDRESSES ah
        ON ah.address_ID = D.address_id
where
    OFFICER_INCIDENTS.ORC_ROLE_CODE = 'R' and
    incident_people_vw.status = 'A' and
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.ROLE_ROLE_TYPE IN ('A','S') and
    trunc((to_number(to_char(offense_status_date,'yyyymmdd'))-to_number(to_char(DOB,'yyyymmdd')))/10000)  <= 17
;
```

**Iteration 2** - identifying mistakenly forgotten cartesian products (i.e. joins without a join predicate, because when you put all your join predicates to your WHERE clause, you *EASILY* forget some)

In this case it's the `PERSON_ADDRESSES` table.

**Iteration 3** - fixing the missing join predicates

```
select distinct
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INC_REPORT_NUMBER,
    trunc((to_number(to_char(offense_status_date,'yyyymmdd')) - to_number(to_char(DOB,'yyyymmdd')))/10000)  as AGE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID,
    OFFENSES.OFFENSE_STATUS_DATE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.AGNCY_CD_AGENCY_CODE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.STATUS,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.SEX_SEX_CODE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.RACE_RACE_CODE,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.LNAME,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.FNAME,
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.DOB,
    OFFENSES.REMARKS,
    OFFENSE_CODES.OFFENSE_DESC,
    P.LONGITUDE,P.LATITUDE,
    suspicion_Codes.DESCRIPTION,
    P.STREET_NUMBER, P.STREET_NAME,P.STREET_CD_STREET_TYPE_CODE,P.CITY,P.STATE_CD_STATE_CODE,P.ZIP5,
    AH.STREET_NUMBER, AH.STREET_NAME,AH.STREET_CD_STREET_TYPE_CODE,AH.CITY,AH.STATE_CD_STATE_CODE,AH.ZIP5
from
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW
    join OFFICER_INCIDENTS
        on OFFICER_INCIDENTS.INC_INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
    join OFFENSES
        on OFFENSES.INC_INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
    join OFFENSE_CODES
        on OFFENSE_CODES.OFFENSE_CODE = OFFENSES.OFFNS_CD_OFFENSE_CODE
    join OFFICERS
        on OFFICERS.OFFICER_ID = OFFICER_INCIDENTS.OFF1_OFFICER_ID
    join INCIDENT_ADDRESSES
        on INCIDENT_ADDRESSES.INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
    join ADDRESSES P
        on P.ADDRESS_ID = INCIDENT_ADDRESSES.ADDRESS_ID
    join offender_suspicions
        on OFFENDER_SUSPICIONS.OFFNSE_INC_INCIDENT_ID = INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.INCIDENT_ID
    join suspicion_Codes
        on SUSPICION_CODES.SUSPICION_CODE = OFFENDER_SUSPICIONS.SUSPICN_CD_SUSPICION_CODE
    join person_addresses D
        on D.<some column> = <some table from the above ones>.<some column from the table>
    JOIN ADDRESSES ah
        ON AH.address_id = D.address_id
where
    OFFICER_INCIDENTS.ORC_ROLE_CODE = 'R' and
    incident_people_vw.status = 'A' and
    INCIDENT_PEOPLE_VW.ROLE_ROLE_TYPE IN ('A','S') and
    trunc((to_number(to_char(offense_status_date,'yyyymmdd'))-to_number(to_char(DOB,'yyyymmdd')))/10000)  <= 17
;
```

**Iteration 4** - fixing the wonderfully strange age calculation, introducing consistent formatting and consistent table aliases to improve readability

```
select distinct
    IP.incident_id, IP.inc_report_number,
--    trunc((to_number(to_char(OFS.offense_status_date,'yyyymmdd')) - to_number(to_char(IP.dob,'yyyymmdd')))/10000)  as age,
    months_between(OFS.offense_status_date, IP.dob) / 12 as age
    OFS.offense_status_date,
    IP.agncy_cd_agency_code, IP.status, IP.sex_sex_code, IP.race_race_code, IP.lname, IP.fname, IP.dob,
    OFS.remarks,
    OC.offense_desc,
    AIA.longitude, AIA.latitude,
    SC.description,
    AIA.street_number, AIA.street_name, AIA.street_cd_street_type_code, AIA.city, AIA.state_cd_state_code, AIA.zip5,
    PAA.street_number, PAA.street_name, PAA.street_cd_street_type_code, PAA.city, PAA.state_cd_state_code, PAA.zip5
from
    incident_people_vw IP
    join officer_incidents OI
        on OI.inc_incident_id = IP.incident_id
    join offenses OFS
        on OFS.inc_incident_id = IP.incident_id
    join offense_codes OC
        on OC.offense_code = OFS.offns_cd_offense_code
    join officers O
        on O.officer_id = OI.off1_officer_id
    join incident_addresses IA
        on IA.incident_id = IP.incident_id
    join addresses AIA
        on AIA.address_id = IA.address_id
    join offender_suspicions OS
        on OS.offnse_inc_incident_id = IP.incident_id
    join suspicion_codes SC
        on SC.suspicion_code = OS.suspicn_cd_suspicion_code
    join person_addresses PA
        on PA.<some column> = <some table alias from the above ones>.<some column from the table>
    join addresses PAA
        on PAA.address_id = PA.address_id
where
    OI.orc_role_code = 'R' and
    IP.status = 'A' and
    IP.role_role_type in ('A','S') and
--    trunc((to_number(to_char(OFS.offense_status_date,'yyyymmdd')) - to_number(to_char(IP.dob,'yyyymmdd')))/10000)  <= 17
    months_between(OFS.offense_status_date, IP.dob) / 12 <= 17
;
```

Enjoy. And from now on **always** use the ANSI join syntax.

Comment: nop77svk - Thank you very much!!! Well Appreciated!!!

Comment: @quicklearner, you're welcome. Please accept my answer for your question, that's how we get rewarded here.

Comment: Answer has been accepted. Thank you.